# Is there a F# type provider for DacPac file

Tags: f#, code-generation, data-access-layer, type-providers, dacpac

I wonder if there is a F# generative type provider that can be bound to a dacpac file that behave like DbmlFile type provider except for a visual studio database project output.

What I am trying to achieve is to use F# type providers as DAL code generation tool for my C# project. I guess I can achieve this by syncing the dacpac to the database and using SqlDataConnection type provider to achieve the same result but it would be great if the need for a database could be eliminated.